# Birkhoff's characterization of varieties of groups

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

A class of groups $\mathcal{V}$ is called a *variety* if there exists a set of words $W$ such that $G$ belongs to $\mathcal{V}$ if and only if
$w(g_1,g_2,\ldots)=1$ for all $w\in W$ and $g_1,g_2,\ldots\in G$.
In Robinson's book ("A course in the theory of groups") the following theorem of Birkhoff (2.3.4 and 2.3.5) is stated and proved:

A class $\mathcal{V}$ of groups is a variety if and only if $\mathcal{V}$ is closed under taking quotients and subdirect products.

Let $\mathcal{V}$ be the smallest variety containing the symmetric group $S_3$. By Birkhoff's theorem, the members of $\mathcal{V}$ can be constructed iteratively from $S_3$ by taking quotients and subdirect products. However, I cannot imagine how the subgroup $C_3\le S_3$ arises in this way (it must be in $\mathcal{V}$ by the definition of varieties). Any ideas?

Comment: Is it clear that taking subdirect products and quotients iteratively will produce a class that is closed under subdirect products and quotients? You may need to go transfinite, as each iteration may produce new groups to put into a subdirect product. E.g., The nontrivial part of the HSP theorem is to show that the class of homomorphic images of subgroups of products *is* closed under products and subgroups. (Though for a finite element of the variety that may not matter...)

Comment: I don't see any argument simpler than just running through Robinson's proof of Birkhoff's theorem in this case. In particular I do not believe it suffices to consider finite subdirect products; Robinson's argument needs a countable one. It seems easier just to state Birkhoff's theorem as "closed under quotients, subgroups, and direct products."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan It's actually a different theorem. Two different characterizations, and the HSP theorem is about how to generate a variety, not just how to characterize it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan that makes sense. I was hoping to see a more explicit construction, preferably using only finite groups. You can turn your comment into an answer if you like.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The proof in Robinson's book indeed gives an explicit construction.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Sort of... You would need to know the identities that are satisfied by $\mathrm{Var}(S_3)$, so that for each identity *not* satisfied you can construct an appropriate subdirect product...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be an infinite countable set. Start from the unrestricted direct power $S_3^D=C_3^D\rtimes C_2^D$. Let $C_2^{(D)}$ be the restricted direct power (=direct sum). Let $G$ be the semidirect product $C_3^D\rtimes C_2^{(D)}$; this is a subdirect product. Write $C_3^{)D(}$ for the near direct power $C_3^D/C_3^{(D)}$. Then $G$ admits the quotient $H=C_3^{)D(}\rtimes C_2^{(D)}$. But one readily sees that the action of $C_2^{(D)}$ on $C_3^{)D(}$ is trivial. So $H$ is the direct product $H=C_3^{)D(}\times C_2^{(D)}$, which admits $C_3$ as quotient.

---

However, one can't obtain $C_3$ from $S_3$ when considering only quotients and finite subdirect products. Indeed, for a finite group $K$ in the variety generated by $S_3$, one has the equivalence between (a) the abelianization of $K$ is a 2-group and (b) the center of $K$ is a 2-group, or (b') the centralizer of every element of order 3 is a proper subgroup. Then (a) passes to quotients, and (b') passes to subdirect products.

Comment: No idea what the downvote is for.

Comment: You probably did not supply enough context ;-)

Comment: Thanks! That's a very clever construction. For the second part, are you saying that (a) and (b) are equivalent? Why?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki a finite group in this variety has the form $G=N\rtimes Q$ for $N$ elementary abelian 3-group and $Q$ elementary abelian 2-group. If $N^Q$ is the centralizer of $Q$ in $N$, then $N^Q$ is the 3-Sylow subgroup of the center of $G$. Then $N^Q$ has a unique $Q$-invariant complement, say $N_Q$. Then the derived subgroup of $G$ is $N_Q$. The abelianization of $G$ is $N^Q\times Q$. In particular the abelianization is a 2-group iff the center is a 2-group (iff $N^Q=0$).

Comment: Ah, I see. You're using the Fitting decomposition $N=C_N(Q)\times [Q,N]$. Thanks again!